# Introducing formula in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, formula, rusle

What is the correct way to introduce this formula in the raster calculator?

It is the formula in order to calculate m-coefficient for L factor for RUSLE model.

O = slope in degrees

[image]

I tried multiple times, it always returned me values, but one time it was: 3.13 and other time: 22.9. I always have problems to get the correct order of operations in Raster calculator.

Comment: @BERA ArcGIS Pro 2.7, raster calculator. I have tried multiple formulas, with various paranthesis, both round and squares. Sadly, I haven't  took screen pics of all of them. This is one of the formula I have typed in: ( Sin("Slope_Fill_e1") /0.0896) /(0.56+3* Power( Sin("Slope_Fill_e1") ,0.8))

Comment: Just do them one by one .eg sin(0) divided etc

Answer (score 1):

I have calculated the above formula step by step, not in raster calculator, and I have compared the result, with the one from the raster calculator.

The raster calculator formula I have posted in the comment, answer to BERA, offered the correct result. I have also checked using an online equation solver, and offered the same result.

Therefore, if someone ever needs to use the above formula in raster calculator, the way I have typed in the formula in raster calculator provided the correct result

```
( Sin("Slope_in_degrees_raster") /0.0896) /(0.56+3* Power( Sin("Slope_in_degrees_raster") ,0.8))
```

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if the problem is solved.